# How can I execute a line after a function is done? in javascript (react native)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've researched about asynchronic functions and related topics here but either I don't get the idea or it doesn't work on my case. What I want to do is very simple, I have these 3 functions

```
Line 1: setOn(true)
Line 2: useFetchSignIn(endpointIn, 'POST', email, password)
Line 3: setOn(false)
```

And I want to execute Line 1,2,3 in that specific order. Since line 2 is a fetch function line 3 needs to wait until 2 is done. What is the best approach to do this?

My best try was this:

```
setOn(true)   

    async function hello() {                            
    await useFetchSignIn(endpointIn, 'POST', email, password)
    await setOn(false)
}

hello()
```

but the result is basically the same as if I never used the function setOn() meaning that line 3 is executing too fast, so it's not working because fetch function takes around 2-3 seconds.

EDIT: the function UseFetchSignIn() is in another .js, down below is what's inside that file:

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import * as Updates from 'expo-updates';

async function reloadApp () {
  await Updates.reloadAsync();
}

export const useFetchSignIn = (endpoint, method, inputEmail, inputPassword)=> {
       
  let account = { email: inputEmail, password: inputPassword };            
  
  fetch(endpoint, {
    method: method, 
    body: JSON.stringify(account), 
    headers:{            
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }}).then(res =>{               
      if(res.status==200) { 
        res.json().then((data) => {
            /* alert(data.message); */
              const saveToken = async () => {
                try {
                  await AsyncStorage.setItem('token', data.token)                  
                  await console.log("Token has been successfully saved in the storage")
                  await reloadApp ();                  
                } catch (e) {
                  console.log(e)
                }
            }
              saveToken();                                          
        });            

      }else res.json().then((data) => {alert(data.error)});              
    })
    .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))              
}
```

Comment: You need to better explain your problem, it's not clear enough

Comment: Did you try to await on setOn

Comment: Please show us how `useFetchSignIn` is defined. I suspect that it does not actually return a promise.

Comment: Đinh Carabus done, it's a little messy though but I'm learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a `return` statement here:

```
export const useFetchSignIn = (endpoint, method, inputEmail, inputPassword, props)=> {
   
    let account = { email: inputEmail, password: inputPassword };            

    return fetch(endpoint, {      // <----------------
```

You want to return the promise object that `fetch` gives you. Currently your function just returns `undefined`, so you are basically saying `await undefined` which will resolve immediately.